# printing out TCP flag information from pcap

Tags: c, networking, hex, pcap

I'm writing a program to get certain pieces of information from the headers in a pcap. I'm not sure if I did this right. It works with all of my professor's tests, however, there are hidden tests that I need to be aware of. It's the TCP flags I'm not sure about. It works in index 47, but don't know why, should be 46. (Ethernet Header(14) + IPv4 header(20) + 13th byte in TCP header (13) -1 (to account for arrays starting at 0) = 46). Is it a fluke that it works on spot 47?

Here's my code:

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
/*
 * Most of this file is the background functionality to open a capture file or to
 * open an inteface for a live capture. You can ignore all this unless you are
 * interested in an example of how pcap works.
 *
 * To use the file, simply insert your code in the "Put your code here" section and
 * create a Makefile for compilation.
 */

/* Maximum time that the OS will buffer packets before giving them to your program. */
#define MAX_BUFFER_TIME_MS (300)

/* Maximum time the program will wait for a packet during live capture.
 * Measured in MAX_BUFFER_TIME_MS units. Program closes when it expires. */
#define MAX_IDLE_TIME 100 /* 100*MAX_BUFFER_TIME_MS idle time at most */

/* Function that creates the structures necessary to perform a packet capture and
 * determines capture source depending on arguments. Function will terminate the
 * program on error, so return value always valid. */
pcap_t* setup_capture(int argc, char *argv[], char *use_file);

/* Cleanup the state of the capture. */
void cleanup_capture(pcap_t *handle);

/* Check for abnormal conditions during capture.
 * 1 returned if a packet is ready, 0 if a packet is not available.
 * Terminates program if an unrecoverable error occurs. */
char valid_capture(int return_value, pcap_t *pcap_handle, char use_file);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  pcap_t *pcap_handle = NULL;             /* Handle for PCAP library */
  struct pcap_pkthdr *packet_hdr = NULL;  /* Packet header from PCAP */
  const u_char *packet_data = NULL;       /* Packet data from PCAP */
  int ret = 0;                            /* Return value from library calls */
  char use_file = 0;                      /* Flag to use file or live capture */

  /* Setup the capture and get the valid handle. */
  pcap_handle = setup_capture(argc, argv, &use_file);

  /* Loop through all the packets in the trace file.
   * ret will equal -2 when the trace file ends.
   * ret will never equal -2 for a live capture. */
  ret = pcap_next_ex(pcap_handle, &packet_hdr, &packet_data);

  struct ether_header
  {
    u_int8_t  ether_dhost[6];   /* destination eth addr */
    u_int8_t  ether_shost[6];   /* source ether addr    */
    u_int16_t ether_type;               /* packet type ID field */
  };
  struct ether_header *eptr;
  char src[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  char dst[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  char src6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  char dst6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

  while( ret != -2 ) {
    if( valid_capture(ret, pcap_handle, use_file) ){
      eptr = (struct ether_header *) packet_data;
      fprintf(stdout,"%s -> ",ether_ntoa((const struct ether_addr *)&eptr->ether_shost));
      fprintf(stdout,"%s \n",ether_ntoa((const struct ether_addr *)&eptr->ether_dhost));
      if(packet_data[12] == 0x08 && packet_data[13] == 0x00)
      {
        printf("    [IPv4] ");
        fprintf(stdout,"%s -> ", inet_ntop(AF_INET,(const void *)packet_data+26,src,INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
        fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET,(const void *)packet_data+30,dst,INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
        if(packet_data[23] == 0x06)
        {
          printf("    [TCP] %d -> ",packet_data[34]*256+packet_data[35]);
          printf("%d ",packet_data[36]*256+packet_data[37]);
        //  printf("%02X ",packet_data[47]); //print out value of flag;
           if(packet_data[47] & (1!=0))
             printf("FIN \n");
             else if((packet_data[47] == 0x02 || packet_data[47] == 0x12) & (2!=0))
             printf("SYN \n");

             else{
             printf("\n");
             }

        }
        else if(packet_data[23] == 0x11)
        {
          printf("    [UDP] %d -> ",packet_data[34]*256+packet_data[35]);
          printf("%d \n",packet_data[36]*256+packet_data[37]);
        }
        else{
          printf("    [%d] \n",packet_data[23]);
        }
      }
      else if(packet_data[12] == 0x86 && packet_data[13] == 0xdd)
      {

        printf("    [IPv6] ");
        printf("%s -> ", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, (const void *)packet_data+22, src6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN));
        printf("%s \n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, (const void *)packet_data+38, dst6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN));

        if(packet_data[20] == 0x06)
        {
          printf("    [TCP] %d -> ",packet_data[54]*256+packet_data[55]);
          printf("%d ",packet_data[56]*256+packet_data[57]);
         // printf("%02X ",packet_data[67]); //print out value of flag

             if(packet_data[67] & (1!=0))
             printf("FIN \n");
             else if((packet_data[67] == 0x02 || packet_data[67] == 0x12) & (2!=0))
             printf("SYN \n");
             else{

          printf("\n");
          }



        }
        else if(packet_data[20] == 0x11)
        {

          printf("    [UDP] %d -> ",packet_data[54]*256+packet_data[55]);
          printf("%d \n",packet_data[56]*256+packet_data[57]);
        }
        else{
          printf("    [%d] \n",packet_data[20]);
        }
      } else {
        fprintf(stdout,"    [%d] \n",ntohs(eptr->ether_type));
      }
    }
    /* Get the next packet */
    ret = pcap_next_ex(pcap_handle, &packet_hdr, &packet_data);
  }

  cleanup_capture(pcap_handle);
  return 0;
}

pcap_t* setup_capture(int argc, char *argv[], char *use_file) {
  char *trace_file = NULL;                /* Trace file to process */
  pcap_t *pcap_handle = NULL;             /* Handle for PCAP library to return */
  char pcap_buff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];       /* Error buffer used by pcap functions */
  char *dev_name = NULL;                  /* Device name for live capture */

  /* Check command line arguments */
  if( argc > 2 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [trace_file]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if( argc > 1 ){
    *use_file = 1;
    trace_file = argv[1];
  }
  else {
    *use_file = 0;
  }

  /* Open the trace file, if appropriate */
  if( *use_file ){
    pcap_handle = pcap_open_offline(trace_file, pcap_buff);
    if( pcap_handle == NULL ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening trace file \"%s\": %s\n", trace_file, pcap_buff);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  /* Lookup and open the default device if trace file not used */
  else{
    dev_name = pcap_lookupdev(pcap_buff);
    if( dev_name == NULL ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error finding default capture device: %s\n", pcap_buff);
      exit(-1);
    }

    /* Use buffer length as indication of warning, per pcap_open_live(3). */
    pcap_buff[0] = 0;

    pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(dev_name, BUFSIZ, 1, MAX_BUFFER_TIME_MS, pcap_buff);
    if( pcap_handle == NULL ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening capture device %s: %s\n", dev_name, pcap_buff);
      exit(-1);
    }
    if( pcap_buff[0] != 0 ) {
      printf("Warning: %s\n", pcap_buff);
    }

    printf("Capturing on interface '%s'\n", dev_name);
  }

  return pcap_handle;

}

void cleanup_capture(pcap_t *handle) {
  /* Close the trace file or device */
  pcap_close(handle);
}

char valid_capture(int return_value, pcap_t *pcap_handle, char use_file) {
  static int idle_count = 0;  /* Count of idle periods with no packets */
  char ret = 0;               /* Return value, invalid by default */

  /* A general error occurred */
  if( return_value == -1 ) {
    pcap_perror(pcap_handle, "Error processing packet:");
    cleanup_capture(pcap_handle);
    exit(-1);
  }

  /* Timeout occured for a live packet capture */
  else if( (return_value == 0) && (use_file == 0) ){
    if( ++idle_count >= MAX_IDLE_TIME ){
      printf("Timeout waiting for additional packets on interface\n");
      cleanup_capture(pcap_handle);
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  /* Unexpected/unknown return value */
  else if( return_value != 1 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected return value (%i) from pcap_next_ex()\n", return_value);
    cleanup_capture(pcap_handle);
    exit(-1);
  }
  /* Normal operation, packet arrived */
  else{
    idle_count = 0;
    ret = 1;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Here's a few sample print outs: (the left is the professors results, the right is mine, I have extra printout to see what's in that spot in the array). Thanks

```
0:0:86:5:80:da -> 0:60:97:7:69:ea                           0:0:86:5:80:da -> 0:60:97:7:69:ea 
    [IPv6] 3ffe:507:0:1:200:86ff:fe05:80da -> 3ffe:501:410:0:2c0:dfff:fe47:33e          [IPv6] 3ffe:507:0:1:200:86ff:fe05:80da -> 3ffe:501:410:0:2c0:dfff:fe47:33e 
    [TCP] 1022 -> 22 SYN                                |       [TCP] 1022 -> 22 02 SYN 
0:60:97:7:69:ea -> 0:0:86:5:80:da                           0:60:97:7:69:ea -> 0:0:86:5:80:da 
    [IPv6] 3ffe:501:410:0:2c0:dfff:fe47:33e -> 3ffe:507:0:1:200:86ff:fe05:80da          [IPv6] 3ffe:501:410:0:2c0:dfff:fe47:33e -> 3ffe:507:0:1:200:86ff:fe05:80da 
    [TCP] 22 -> 1022 SYN                                |       [TCP] 22 -> 1022 12 SYN
```

Comment: Can you show that "math" you did to arrive at the index you believe the flags should be at?

Comment: His math is correct.  The offset from the start of an ethernet frame to the TCP flags (assuming it is a TCP packet with no IP options) is 47.  14 + 20 + 13

Comment: yeah which explains why 47 is correct, but I'm accessing these in an array which starts at 0. Thought I needed to subtract 1.

Comment: Look at my answer below.  It works it all out for you from a zero based offset array/in the frame/packet

Comment: Cool right on, thank you, I'm examing it now. I got the Ethernet Info, IP info, and UDP info already. It's just the last step with the TCP header (got source and dest ports already). Also only need SYN and FIN flags.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer So his "math" is correct IFF `46  == 47`. Well, some people embrace insanity more easily than others.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Sorry, I meant that 47 was a correct number.  I missed that he was using it as an offset. :) @EOF

Comment: @Mike1982 I thought you were looking for SYN and ACK.  You'll have to modify what I filtered for for the FIN rather than the ACK

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can locate the TCP flags:

If we assume that we are talking about Ethernet, the Ethernet frame header will be 14 bytes:  a 6 byte destination followed by a 6 byte source and then a 2 byte ether type (for 802.3/SNAP/Ethernet II, which is most likely)

If the Ethertype at offset 12/13 from the start of the frame contains 0x0800, you are looking at TCP/IP.

```
 if(frame[12]==0x08 && frame[13]==0x00) { /* IP packet inside */ }
```

Assuming that you have an IP Ethertype, the next byte will contain two nibble sized fields:  The IP version number (likely 0x40 for you) and then the IP header length (likely 0x05).  Putting those nibbles together, you would have 0x45 sitting in that field.  It is *very important* to check that field.  You could mask off the upper nibble like so:

```
  ihl = frame[14]&0x0f;
```

to grab the IP header length field.  This number will tell you where to find the next protocol layer's header.  Typically you will have a 5 here (20 byte header), but if there are IP options, this number will be larger.  Let's take this number and calculate from here:

```
  embedded_protocol_header = frame[ihl * 4];
```

Next, you should verify that you actually have a TCP packet.  This can be verified by examining byte offset 9 in the IP header:

```
  ip_header_start = frame[14];
  embedded_protocol = ip_header_start[9];
  if(embedded_protocol == 6) { tcp_header = embedded_protocol_header; }
```

Now that we know it is TCP, we can grab the TCP flags.  These will be at offset 13 in the TCP header:

```
  tcp_flags = tcp_header[13];
```

To examine the SYN/ACK bits, you can mask everything else off:

```
  synack = tcp_flags & 0x3f;
```

You can now check to see if it's a SYN ACK:

```
  if(synack == 0x12) { /* SYN and ACK were set */
```

You may wonder about the 0x3f mask above.  The reason for it is that the two high order bits in the TCP flags are used for ECN if the system supports ECN.  If it is supported, ECN negotiation occurs during the 3 way handshake in these bits and the two low order bits in the TOS byte of the IP header (differentiated services byte).  Rather than dealing with all of the possible cases, the simplest thing is to turn those bits off completely and check to see if you still have SYN and ACK.

Comment: Ok so what does the 0x12 for synack == 0x12 represent?. I thought 0x01 is FIN, and 0x02 is for SYN.

Comment: 0x01 is FIN.  0x02 is SYN.  0x10 is ACK.  I misread and thought you were trying to find SYN ACK packets, which would be 0x10 | 0x02 = 0x12

Comment: You really ought to create a set of conditionals to test each bit in the TCP flags individually to print out the full set of flags that are enabled in a given packet.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help and explanation. One last question, is the tcp_flags variable built into the tcp.h, so it has all the information from the pcap already?

Comment: You'd have to look.  I don't know offhand.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I started doing it your way and my code got all cluttered and creating a bunch of new variables and it didn't work. I'm updating my code with what I got. It works with the professors test file, but I'm not sure why. He has hidden tests as well, so not sure if there's a check I missed. Posted is my entire code. Thanks